# regex - how to make an exceptioin of a spcific string in regex

Tags: regex

i have the folwing problem in regex
i want to get just the string from that pattern of regex

```
#10 12:00:00 - some text
#100 11:04:00 ! some text
#2 23:01:10 ? some text
```

this is pretty easy and the answer to that in regex will be

```
#[0-9]+ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [-,!,?].*
```

but it gets much more complicated if I want to filter as well all the inputs i get with the time 00:00:00.

it is possible but it's really ugly is there any megical beautiful way to do this with a simple regex

Comment: Note that `[-,!,?]` matches 1 of 4 chars: `-`, `,`, `!`, `?`. Remove all `,` if you do not want to match a comma.

Comment: "but it gets much more complicated if I want to filter as well all the inputs i get with the time 00:00:00"  Does it have to be done in one pass?  Could you do capture groups and run the filtering at the application level instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead `(?!00:00:00)` in the regex at the start

(?!00:00:00) fails when it matches the regex inside

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: tnx that's exactly what i was looking for!!

Comment: Nice to see more people who master lookaheads. +1